# Why did numbered list stop working after I hit Enter?

Tags: styles

I have a numbered list like:

```
1.0 Excel 2010
    1.1 Introduction to Excel 2010
         1.1.A. A general overview of Excel 2010, geared towards beginners
         1.1.B. There are 3 videos in this series
```

I put the cursor at the end of the last line on 1.1.B and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  The next line should begin with 1.1.C but nothing appears when the cursor returns to the next line.

Another example, if I put the cursor at the end of 1.1.A and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I should get a new 1.1.B and the original 1.1.B should be renamed to 1.1.C.  After hitting enter, a new 1.1.B doesn't appear and the previous 1.1.B drops all the way to the next page.

So the next bullet number that should come up doesn't come up.  I tried [Microsoft Fix It](http://support.microsoft.com/fixit/) to reset the Registry and that didn't work either.

This is very frustrating.  Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: In... Microsoft Word?

Comment: What happens when you start typing on the new line? I have this problem occasionally, but when I start typing the number shows up.